# Nested loop in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I am having a simple nested while loop in stored procedure , but it's giving an error.
The loop does not nothing great, just for learning purpose i created two loops.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getSum(in input int , out output int)
begin

set output = 0;
while input >= 1 do

  declare tmp int default 1;
  while tmp <= 5 do
      set  output = output + input ;
      set tmp = tmp + 1;
   end while ;

set input = input - 1 ;

end while;

end $$
delimiter ;
```

Below is the error

**`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare tmp int default 1; while tmp <= 5 do set output = output + inpu' at line 7`**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getSum(in input int , out output int)
begin
declare tmp int default 1;
set output = 0;
while input >= 1 do

  set tmp = 1;
  while tmp <= 5 do
      set  output = output + input ;
      set tmp = tmp + 1;
   end while ;

set input = input - 1 ;

end while;

end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: what was wrong with my code? Do i have to declare local variables every time like this?

Comment: I moved the `declare` to the beginning of the block, and added `set tmp = 1;` to be consistent with the value you had initialized it with.

Comment: Local variables are defined relative to a `BEGIN...END` block. Usually, defining them at the beginning of the block eliminates errors like this. I think that it is a requirement to define them first-thing in the block, like in old procedural languages... but I may be wrong.

Comment: nested while loop doing nothing in mysql

Comment: It's demo code. Not supposed to do anything. Just to illustrate a concept.